Netplan config is not being applied
I've just installed a Ubuntu 24.04 LTS VM. The IP address configured using the installation wizards works perfectly. But when I try to configure my own IP address with Netplan config file, running netplan apply doesn't really changes the IP.
I've removed the initial Netplan YAML file created by the OS installer.
Running netplan --debug apply also doesn't really outputs anything unsual. Please refer to my config below for /etc/netplan/main.yml file I've created:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      addresses:
        - 10.0.121.X/24
      link-local: []
      mtu: 9190
    ens192:
      addresses:
        - 10.0.122.X/24
      link-local: []
      mtu: 9190
    ens224:
      dhcp4: false
      link-local: []
      mtu: 9190
    lo:
      addresses:
        - 10.0.118.X/32
      link-local: []
  tunnels:
    vxlan10027:
      mode: vxlan
      local: 10.0.118.X
      id: 10027
      link: lo
      mac-learning: false
      port: 4789
  bridges:
    cloudbr1:
      interfaces:
        - vxlan10027
      addresses:
        - 10.0.113.X/24
      link-local: []
      nameservers:
        addresses:
          - 1.1.1.1
          - 8.8.8.8
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.113.X
      mtu: 9190
      stp: false

netplan --debug apply output

The extension for netplan config files is .yaml, not .yml.
